# how to load new page that being generated with dropdown list onchange?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have below code..  I need it open this page  **bill_report.asp?q=yrSelect**  after user select one of this generated year. Try to google a lot but couldn't find the suitable code for me. So could you please help me out. thank you very much

```
   <select name="inyear" id="inyear" onChange="??">
     <option value="0" <%=yrSelect%>>SELECT YEAR</option>
     <option value="0" <%=yrSelect%>>ALL YEARS</option>  

        <%
        dim yearCount, YearStart, yrValue, z
        YearStart = 2012
        yearCount = 0

        z = current_year - YearStart                                 

        do while not yearCount > z
           yrValue = current_year - yearCount

        %>    

      <option value="<%=yrValue%>" <%=yrSelect%>><%=yrValue%></option>                                   
         <%
            yearCount = yearCount + 1
            loop
         %>
   </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're over complicating it way too much. All you need is such code:

```
<form action="<%=Request.ServerVariables("Script_Name")%>" method="GET">
    <select name="inyear" id="inyear" onChange="this.form.submit();">
        <option value="-1" <%=CheckSelected(-1)%>>SELECT YEAR</option>
        <option value="0" <%=CheckSelected(0)%>>ALL YEARS</option>  
        <%=GenerateYears(2012)%>
    </select>
</form>
```

And the ASP code should be:

```vbs
<%
Function CheckSelected(yearValue)
    If Request("inyear")=CStr(yearValue) Then
        CheckSelected = "selected=""selected"""
    Else  
        CheckSelected = ""
    End If
End Function

Function GenerateYears(YearStart)
    Dim arrOptions, currentYear, x
    ReDim arrOptions(-1)
    currentYear = Year(Now())
    For x=YearStart To currentYear
        ReDim Preserve arrOptions(UBound(arrOptions) + 1)
        arrOptions(UBound(arrOptions)) = "<option value=""" & x & """ " & CheckSelected(x) &">" & x & "</option>"
    Next
    GenerateYears = Join(arrOptions, VBCrLf)
    Erase arrOptions
End Function
%>
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, what i understood is that this ASP code is going to generate a select-options block like the following on or similar. And what you want to do is that after selecting an option, you want to go to another ASP page to process the form passing a variable q=yrSearch and another variable, the year you chose. Is it right?

```
<select name="" id="">
    <option value="">2014</option>
    <option value="">2013</option>
    <option value="">2012</option>
    <option value="">2011</option>
    <option value="">2010</option>
    <option value="">2009</option>
</select>
```

I never worked with ASP before but i assume that in passing variables through the URL, it may function more or less like PHP.
In a HTML Form Block you generate always a structure like that:

```
<form action="bill_report.asp" method="get" id="myForm">
<input type="hidden" name="q" value="yrSelect">

<select name="name_of_select" value="" onChange="change_function(this.selectedIndex)">
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    <option value="2009">2009</option>
</select>
```

If you take a look to the web page of W3CSchools (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp), you can see that you can modify the attribute value for a SELECT block too.

The only thing you have to do is, when you select an option, let javascript get the value of the selected OPTION and set it in the whole SELECT block. So when you submit, the variable of select will be passed to URL as well.
And when the selection is done, you have to call the method submit() of the FORM, so the form is submitted with the values.

If you want to pass variables, which you already know. Like the one that you pointed out before: q=yrSelect, I would use a INPUT HIDDEN form item, so you can pass the variable secure and fast.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
var select = document.body.querySelector('select');
var options = document.body.querySelectorAll('option');

function change_function (index) {
  select.value = options[index].value;
  form.submit();
}
</script>
```